# Why on Yom Tov does the brocho in Amida change to "בְּךָ"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shemoneh-esrei, yom-tov

Hi gut moed / moadim lesimcha everyone!

Does anyone know / have a source for why on Yom Tov at the end of the brocho in [shemonei esrei](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Festivals%2C_Shalosh_Regalim%2C_Amida_for_Maariv%2C_Shacharit%2C_Mincha%2C_Sanctity_of_the_Day.22?vhe=Daat_Siddur_Ashkenaz&lang=bi) we say:

> וְיִשמְחוּ **בְּךָ** יִשרָאֵל

And yet on [Shabbos](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Shabbat%2C_Shacharit%2C_Amidah%2C_Sanctity_of_the_Day.4?vhe=Daat_Siddur_Ashkenaz&lang=bi) we say:

> וְיָנוּחוּ **בו (בה\בם)** יִשרָאֵל

In other words, we say we will rest **on** Shabbos but on Yom Tov we will have simcha (joy/happiness) in/with **YOU**?

Is it literally a case that it is a different avodas hayom - that perhaps Yom Tov is a celebration with Hashem as opposed to Shabbos when we recognise His creation and is maybe more of celebration of Hashem?

Comment: The question is backwards. The old nusach had בך on Shabbat as well. It was וישמחו בך ישראל אוהבי שמך. Someone thought that wasn't very related to Shabbat and changed it and didn't care much about consistency with Yom Tov

Comment: That's interesting thank you @DoubleAA - Does anyone bring this down?

Comment: The classic article is in one of the earlier volumes of shorshei minhag ashkenaz

Comment: Yom Tob is in the aspect of אתערותא דלתתא while Shabbat is in the aspect of אתערותא דלעילה. So Bakh and Bkha respectively fit